# .Net TCP/IP send character with Ctrl Key modifier

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tcpclient, tcp

I am interfacing with a piece of hardware via a TCP/IP socket, however the documentation is limited.

At present I can get the response I am after by sending Ctrl+G in Putty which prints as '^G'

How can i replicate this in code? I can send 'G' but I'm not sure how to modify it with 'Ctrl'

```
Dim buffer = Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd & vbNewLine)
ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) 'ns = Network Stream
ns.Flush()
```

I am working in VB.Net however examples in C# are fine.

Comment: Send a byte with the value 7 (*BEL*). Ctrl+Letter is just one way to input [control characters](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php) (the original meaning of "control").

Comment: Thanks, just found it myself, seems obvious once you know.

Answer (score 1):

The Ctrl button isn't actuall sent, the Ctrl button + a character acts as a shortcut to a number of ASCII control charachters. In this case Ctrl+G sends the  (ASCII value 007) control character (printed as ^G)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII